# How can I decide all input samples are from populations with equal variances？

Tags: python, pandas

How can I decide all input samples are from populations with equal variances？

I wrote codes:

```
#coding:utf-8
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[23. 45. 78. 23. 48.][36. 94. 34. 10. 40.]]
result= sp.stats.bartlett(*data)
print(result)
```

When I run this codes,

```
BartlettResult(statistic=4.3945586749853556, pvalue=0.8593505896)
```

is shown.
 But I can't know this value says  whether all input samples has equal variances or not. Is it a numeric standard to decide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bartlett test` is for testing the `homogeneity` of `variance` across groups, tests the `null hypothesis` that all input samples are from populations with `equal variances`.

So `Test statistic` can be defined as

```
Test statistic = Var(data group1) / Var(data group2)
```

Now, You must be having some criteria of `critical region (cr)` to decide if `cr > Test Statics`, in order to decide whether to accept or reject groups for assumption of having groups or equal variance. If you don't know how to decide or calculate critical region, refer below.

Follow this reference for clear example [Check Here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda357.htm)

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have a question, your answer means I have to calculate criteria by the code `Test statistic = Var(data group1) / Var(data group2)`,right?And do  I have to do it many times if I have data like `data = [[23. 45. 78. 23. 48.][36. 94. 34. 10. 40.][32. 12. 41. 11. 75.][12. 45. 90. 82. 49.]]`?

Comment: If I have multiple data like  data = [[23. 45. 78. 23. 48.][36. 94. 34. 10. 40.][32. 12. 41. 11. 75.][12. 45. 90. 82. 49.]],how can I decide criteria?

Comment: Yes, you have to find out in pairs if their variances are equal. Please go through the link I attached, we need at-least one pair to calculate.